# Using environment variables in Jenkins

Tags: shell, jenkins

Following is a screenshot of how I am setting an environment variable in Jenkins.

[image]

I am trying to access it in a shell script, but it is not echoing its value.

```
echo "Starting ..."

echo ${BUILD_NUMBER}

echo ${DATABASE}
```

`${BUILD_NUMBER}` is a global env variable.

Comment: Are you not able to echo the value of just DATABASE variable or both BUILD_NUMBER and DATABASE variables?

Comment: I am unable to echo the value of either of those variables.

Answer (score 0):

The correct use of variables in Jenkins is the following:

```
echo "The current build number is: ${BUILD_NUMBER}"
```

The important part is to use `"`. If you would use `'` Jenkins would not notice that you want to access the variable and simply print your variable as string.

Source: [Jenkins String Interpolation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#string-interpolation)

Comment: This is what is printed in the output - `The current build number is: `. I need it to print the `build_number`, but it is just printing an empty string.

Comment: If you execute it in a Jenkinsfile it should work properly